# An equality of inner products of holomorphic curves

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

The following is the main result in the paper by Vinnikov, Putinar, Alpay: [A Hilbert space approach to bounded analytic extension in the ball](http://dx.doi.org/10.3934/cpaa.2003.2.139), 2003, Communications on Pure and Applied Analysis. The authors proved it by using Nevanlinna-Pick interpolation theorem and several results from functional analysis.

Let $F:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{B}$ be an injective
holomorphic map. Here $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{B}$ denote the unit
disk in $\mathbb{C}$ and the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$, respectively.
Assume further that $F$ can be extended to be $C^{1}$ on an open
neighbourhood $U$ of $\mathbb{D}$ such that $F\left(z\right)\in\partial\mathbb{B}$
if and only if $z\in\partial\mathbb{D}$; and moreover 
$$
\left\langle F'\left(z\right),F\left(z\right)\right\rangle \neq0,\forall z\in\partial\mathbb{D}.
$$
Prove that 
$$
\left\langle F\left(u\right),F\left(v\right)\right\rangle =\left\langle u,v\right\rangle ;\forall u,v\in\mathbb{D}.
$$
Here $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot\right\rangle $ is the standard inner
product, $\left\langle z,w\right\rangle =z_{1}\overline{w_{1}}+\ldots+z_{n}\overline{w_{n}}$
if $z,w\in\mathbb{C}^{n};$ and $\partial U$ denotes the boundary of
$U.$

Do anyone have another simple approach for this problem?